# How to bind data Modal window (MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a Person class to hold data for Personel and their children as follows:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }

    public Person()
    { }
    public Person(int id, string firstname, string surname)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.FirstName = firstname;
        this.Surname = surname;
    }
}
```

I am listing them on my View as follows:

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Person>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<table style="border: 1px solid #000;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surname</th>
            <th>Children</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000;">@Model[i].FirstName</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000;">@Model[i].Surname</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid #000;">
                    @if (Model[i].Children != null && Model[i].Children.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (MvcApplication1.Controllers.Person child in Model[i].Children)
                        {
                            @child.FirstName  @child.Surname
                        }
                    }
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything is good so far. Then I want to add a jQuery modal window to show the details of the children clicked. So update the most inner-loop as:

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowChildDetails(@child.Id)">@child.FirstName  @child.Surname</a>
```

and add the following method to post AJAX call to fetch details of the child clicked.

```
function ShowChildDetails(_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Home/GetChild",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            id: _id
        },
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (x, t, m, b) {
            alert(x.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

To show data I implement the following jQuery modal window:

```
$(function () {
    $("#child-view").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 600,
        dialogClass: 'no-close',
        modal: true,
        buttons: [
            {
                text: "OK",
                click: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }],
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 300
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "puff",
            duration: 300
        }
    });
});
```

and update the `success` of the AJAX call as :

```
$("#child-view").html(result);
$("#child-view").dialog("open");
```

I implement the look of my modal in another partial view:

**(POINT #1)**:

```
@Html.Partial("ChildView", Model)
```

and implement my partial view as:

**(POINT #2)**:

```
@model List<MvcApplication1.Controllers.Person>
<div id="child-view" class="ui-modal-window" title="">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@Model.Surname</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

First of all, let's check **POINT #1**. Since I am declaring a partial view, I have to provide a data source (*Model* in this example) but as I check the partial view **POINT #2** I see that my partial View need single item, not a collection. On the other hand, at my View I don't know which item to bind and design time. My first question is how should I fix this?

The second issue, I want to bind models properties to partial View with jQuery AJAX call, without postback. And I don't want to set values in each controller by hand. As long as my `Home/GetChild` returns an object of type `Person`, how can I bind the properties shorthand?

Finally suppose that the modal window is not display only, but editable. How can I collect form data, map it to model (`Person` in this case) and send it as a parameter to another AJAX method?

Regards.

Comment: As you want to take single item.. why you had taken List in model. model List<MvcApplication1.Controllers.Person> change it to model MvcApplication1.Controllers.Person.      To call modal from ajax. pass partial views URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: No need to use `@Html.Partial("ChildView", Model)` in your page. Because you are loading partial view through ajax call. So Element `div#child-view` will be empty.

2: Move`<div id="child-view" class="ui-modal-window" title=""></div>` to your main view.

3.Change your partial view as below

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.Person   
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (Model != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.FirstName</td>
                    <td>@Model.Surname</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This partial view result will set to your target element `div#child-view` as your code in ajax success event.

4.Model of your controller action which returns Partial view will be a single `Person` object.

5.If you want to edit the details change the partial view as shown below

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.Person

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveActionName","ControllerName",new AjaxOptions { onSuccess= "onSaveSuccess" }))
{
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.FirstName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Surname)</td>
                </tr>

            <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

in javascript define callback

```
function onSaveSuccess()
{
    alert('saved');
    //your code...
}
```

Hope it will helps you. If so mark it as answer and vote for it. :)

Comment: I have emptied my <div> and moved it to my main page. My partial view is set as table data only with a model of single class Person. I have updated my Action to return not JsonResult but ActionResult and finally I return data as return PartialView("ChildView", child); But when I call this instead of isplaying it in the modal window, it show the html in a pop-up.

Comment: Whether partial view result is coming in your ajax success or not ? ..If not, plz change your ajax dataType: "html". and you can return PartialViewResult.

Comment: Just works perfectly as needed. Thank you very much for your help.